# Strange behaviour of load data infile

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have the following simple CSV file which I want to load into a MySQL table:

```
ViolationUtil1,RU
FiftyFifty2013_prof1,UM
Lunch_util1,RM
...
```

It contains several rows with two fields separated by a comma. I load it using the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'domains.txt'
INTO TABLE domains
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

The table domains is defined in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
    domain varchar(63),
    code varchar(3)
);
```

Strangely, the first letter of the first column disappears!

```
mysql> select * from domains;
+----------------------+------+
| domain               | code |
+----------------------+------+
  |iolationUtil1       | RU
  |iftyFifty2013_prof1 | UM
  |unch_util1          | RM
+----------------------+------+
```

When I changed the definition of the "code" column to:

```
code char(2)
```

I mysteriously got the correct result:

```
mysql> select * from domains;
+----------------------+------+
| domain               | code |
+----------------------+------+
| ViolationUtil1       | RU   |
| FiftyFifty2013_prof1 | UM   |
| Lunch_util1          | RM   |
+----------------------+------+
```

What is happening here?

Comment: would adding "lines terminated by" clause change anything?

Comment: Yes! Adding "LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"" solved the problem (the file comes from a Windows system and I am on Linux...)

Comment: nice, good luck further :)